# Why am I getting the no exported member error in this React/Typescript app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

[image]

**The router.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Route, HashRouter, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import { LoginContainer } from './containers';

export const AppRouter: React.StatelessComponent<{}> = () => {
  return (
    <HashRouter>
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <Route component={App} />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={LoginContainer} />
          <Route path="/login" component={LoginContainer} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </HashRouter>
  );
}
```

**The Folder structure:**

[image]

**The src/containers/index.ts**

```
export * from './auth/LoginContainer';
```

**Finally the LoginContainer**

```
import * as React from 'react';

class LoginContainer extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <header>
          <h1>This is the Login Container</h1>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LoginContainer;
```

Comment: Try removing the braces around the import `import LoginContainer from './containers';` it should then know that it is a `default`

Comment: I tried that, but actually this is how I should have exported the LoginContainer `export class LoginContainer` and Andy's solution below also works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to export the default as named.

```
export { default as LoginContainer } from './auth/LoginContainer';
```

More:  http://jamesknelson.com/re-exporting-es6-modules/

Comment: He should be able to just use import without the braces since it is a `default` like this: `import LoginContainer from './containers';`

Comment: The point of a file like `containers/index.tsx` is to re-export multiple components from the same file, so you can `import { MyComponent } from 'containers'` without having to know where it lives. Importing default will never apply here

Comment: Thanks! I also found that using `export class LoginContainer` and removing the `export default LoginContainer;` line also fixed the issue.